# unnecessary operations in seq2seq.py#model_with_buckets

Tags: tensorflow

Take seq2seq tutorial for example, suppose we have buckets with [(5,5),(10,10)] and batch size 16:
model_with_buckets is used to build the model. For input of model_with_buckets(which is encoder_inputs), it's a batch from one bucket, eg. the size is 5*16
However, there's code to run this batch to all buckets, even if it's size is different from the bucket size

```
# tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py
# in def model_with_buckets()
# this will run twice: seq2seq(encoder_inputs[:5],...) and seq2seq(encoder_inputs[:10],...)
# but encoder_inputs only belongs to bucket (5,5) and with size 5*16
for j, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
    ...
    bucket_outputs, _ = seq2seq(encoder_inputs[:bucket[0]],
                                decoder_inputs[:bucket[1]])
```

And when output, only the loss of bucket which encoder_inputs belongs to will be used.

```
# models/tutorials/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py
# in def step()
output_feed = [self.updates[bucket_id],  # Update Op that does SGD.
               self.gradient_norms[bucket_id],  # Gradient norm.
               self.losses[bucket_id]]  # Loss for this batch.
```

So it seems to me model_with_buckets is doing unnecessary work to feed encoder_inputs to other buckets which it doesn't belong to. What's the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The code is in the phase of graph composition.That is the point.
When linked with session , the step() function will select the specific bucket.